# Python / Selenium - "chromedriver" executable needs to be in a PATH

Tags: python, selenium

I was trying to do something with a gecko driver ( Selenium in this case ) and I can't get my chrome driver to work. Knowing that I am on Mac Sierra, and that my script is in the same folder as my chrome driver, here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://accounts.google.com/signup/v2/webcreateaccount?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=SignUp"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
driver.get(url)
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test if it actually is in the PATH, Open your command prompt go to the location of your chromedriver and hit enter. you will get below message:

```
C:\>
chromedriver.exe
Starting ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68 (420c9498db8ce8fcd190a954d51297672c1515d5-ref
s/branch-heads/3809@{#864}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent
 access by malicious code.
```

Then you need to setup PATH like below before you start your test:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
```

Comment: Well I guess it isn't on the PATH, the command "doesn't exist"

Comment: install chrome driver https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/ and then try. If you want to execute your test on a chrome browser

Comment: what is ot working can you please let me know your error?

Comment: It's the same error but I solved it it was really stupid I didn't put a / before the Users

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/users/usr/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")

url = 'your website'

driver.get(url)
```

make sure you are using this slash (/) in your file path to the chrome driver (as shown above)

Comment: Geckodriver is for Mozilla Firefox. Makesure your using Chrome Webdriver.Try reinstalling the chromedriver (https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)